# How NOT to skip tests in my maven test project?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit

I have created a maven project, it has a number of classes inside it. Each class has test methods, and these are annotated with @Test, and each method starts with "test.." string.
I can individually run the java file over Junit, and can see the result(red.green and similar details).

What I want is, to run all the tests in all the java files, in single go.

I have tried "mvn test" command. But when I run it, this shows "Tests are skipped" and when i try to add below to surefire plugin, I get error that this is not supported.

```
<skip>false</skip>
```

also tried
`mvn test -Dmaven.test.skip=false`
but it also performed in similar manner

> After suggestion below, I added the files inside "src/test/java". now
>   again, i am getting same issue.

`[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) @ com.project.cq.i18n.it.http ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.`

Comment: Show some samples of your tests and the configuration in your pom file

Comment: Can you provide your project structure.

Comment: I need, that after mvn test command, the xml file is created in my target folder of project.
I have edited above question. @ravthiru, can you please help out here?

Comment: can you provide snapshot of project structure and complete error message

Answer (score 1):

All your Junit test classes should be in `src/test/java/` and class names should end or start with `Test`

Comment: this helped me find out the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: added the new error after adding the file to the src/test/java